# Access Dynamically Created Content In Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create some dynamic elements in javascript using jquery pop them into a variable and then access them. I am wondering whether the following is somehow possible?

```
var content=$("<div>Person<div>Name</div><div>Surname</div></div>");
content.find("div").each(function(){
//do something
});
```

Comment: Yes, that is entirely possible.  In fact, what you have shown works fine.  What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery provides [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method which can be used like this.

```
var content=$("<div>Person<div>Name</div><div>Surname</div></div>");
content.find("div").each(function(){
   $(this).addClass( "foo" );
});
```

But obviously, the changes will be visible only if you add them to the DOM as right now these elements are in a seperate [DocumentFragment](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=documentfragment&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CD8QFjAB&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DocumentFragment&ei=1B72UOPdPIm0rAfp5oHwBQ&usg=AFQjCNGF0eq4FA9ENSINM9enr63_LF0DQA&bvm=bv.41018144,d.bmk).

Comment: Thx very much for your informative answer. I wasn't aware of this document fragment thing.